# Form Field not showing up

Tags: python, django, forms

I have the following code in Django for a Form.

```
class ProductAddToCartForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'2', 'value':'1', 'class':'quantity', 'maxlength':'5'}), error_messages={'invalid':'Please enter a valid quantity.'}, min_value =1)

    product_slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    sizes_available = []
    sizes_available.append(7)
    sizes_available.append(9)
    size = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=sizes_available)
```

However when I compile this the `ChoiceField`, `CharField` and the `IntegerField` doesn't show up. When I comment out the line with `size = ...` then `IntegerField` and `CharField` shows up. I think there is something wrong with my `ChoiceField` declaration but I'm not sure what exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield

Choices must be

> An iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) of 2-tuples to use as choices for
>   this field.

Try to .`append((7,7))`

Comment: Ah I think I missed that. Thanks. Out of curiosity why was it designed like this you think?

Comment: The first element is the value (actally send with the form) while the second is the description of the value (verbose name)